# Raphael JS: scale/getBBox of a complex path is MUCH slower in IE than in Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: path, raphael, scale

I have a fairly complex path in Raphael (500 coordinates).

When I use scale() in Chrome or Firefox it scales almost instantly (0.05 sec) but in IE, it can take up to 2 seconds !

I think it has to do with the complexity of the path, because a simple path with 10 coordinates does scale fast.

But why is there SUCH a difference between browsers. I know Chrome/Firefox uses SVG and IE uses VML, but the scale() function is something of the Raphael-library itself, isnt it?

What's also strange, is that when I scale() and then do a getBBox(), sometimes the scale() takes a long time, and sometimes the getBBox()....randomly....

Any way to get IE a little bit faster with complex paths?

Answer (score 0):

IE is much slower than Chrome/Firefox for all JS work, not only complex ones.

There is no way to speed up IE with just JS code (except if you can optimize scale() function itself).

I think the better way is to use a simpler path for IE users if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I found that complex paths, that is paths with lots of coordinates, render faster if you do any scaling inside your own javascript code before building the string you pass to Raphael, rather than scaling it through Raphael's [scale](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#scale) function. This is also true for the translate function.

Comment: I'm not building the paths myself but get them from an SVG-file  (d-attribute)...